# How to convert rows into columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Current data in excel

| Fruit | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Apple | 2 |
| Mango | 3 |
| Mango | 3 |

Expected output

| Fruit | Quantity | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 | 2 |
| Mango | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Enumerate rows within fruit group then create pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
In cell D2:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A5)
```

If the UNIQUE function is not applicable, you can try the method in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to get the unique value.
In cell E2:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5, SMALL(IF($D2=$A$2:$A$5, ROW($A$2:$A$5)-ROW($A$1)),COLUMN(A1)))
```

[image]